# How are regular languages not structurally recursive?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, recursion

[This blog posting](https://matt.might.net/articles/parsing-with-derivatives/) states that *"regular languages aren't structurally recursive"* while
*"That's not the case for context-free grammars"*

In what sense is the term "structurally recursive" meant here?

Answer (score 1):

Regular languages don't have recursive structures, so formally regular expressions cannot express recursive structures by definition.All regular languages can be recognized by a finite automaton. A finite automaton has a finite number of states, and consequently, finite memory .

A recursive "regular" expression requires a potentially infinite stack space to do the recursion, thus it is not possible to recognize it with a finite automaton, therefore it is not regular.But for CFL it's true.